# Rust: Reference to a generic parameter doesn't satisfy trait bound

Tags: generics, methods, rust, reference, traits

I'm trying to write a simple TCP client in Rust that asks the user whether or not they want their connection to be SSL. I'm trying to abstract as much code out as possible, so I'm attempting to write a "communicate_with_server" function that should be able to take in a `SslStream` or a `TcpStream`.

```rust
fn communicate_with_server<T: std::io::Read + std::io::Write>(mut stream: T) {
    let initial_message = format!("hello world");
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let _bytes_written = stream.write_all(initial_message.as_bytes());
    let _flush = stream.flush();

    loop {
        let mut stream_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
        stream_reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Reading into buffer failed");
        // ... Wait for the server to respond and do some analysis on the response ...
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following response:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&T: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:47:48
   |
47 |         let mut stream_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
   |                                                -^^^^^^
   |                                                |
   |                                                the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `&T`
   |                                                help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
   |
   = note: required by `BufReader::<R>::new`

error[E0599]: no method named `read_until` found for struct `BufReader<&T>` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:49:23
   |
49 |         stream_reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Reading into buffer failed");
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `BufReader<&T>`
   |
```

The second error makes sense given the first, but I'm not quite sure why `&T` doesn't implement the `Read` trait.

Answer (score 3):

`&T` where `T: Read` does not impl `Read` because many of the `Read` trait methods require mutating `T` which is not possible with a `&T`, i.e. an *immutable* reference to `T`.

To fix your issue you should instead pass a *mutable* reference, i.e. `&mut stream`, to `BufReader::new` like this:

```rust
use std::io::{ Read, Write, BufReader, BufRead };

fn communicate_with_server<T: Read + Write>(mut stream: T) {
    let initial_message = format!("hello world");
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let _bytes_written = stream.write_all(initial_message.as_bytes());
    let _flush = stream.flush();

    loop {
        let mut stream_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
        stream_reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Reading into buffer failed");
        // ... Wait for the server to respond and do some analysis on the response ...
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1249550c61d22fc82d0e01fee3fe64b8)

Comment: That makes sense thanks! Is there a way I can create a mutable reference instead of an immutable one?

Comment: Yes, you can create a mutable reference with `&mut stream` and you could pass that mutable reference to `BufReader::new` since `&mut T: Read` where `T: Read`. I've updated my answer with this detail.

Comment: @fermi if my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking on the gray checkmark underneath the answer score, thanks!